# Creating a way to navigate back when using jQuery for AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I am dynamically loading content into part of a page using jQuery `.load()`. 
It is working well, but I am having trouble building a way for the user to navigate back to the original content after the new content has been loaded.

I have created a 'close' icon with css which exists on the new page which is loaded, but I am not sure how to set up the jQuery / JavaScript in order for it to navigate the user back to the original state of that part of the page.

This is the relevant js:

```
// pages to load
var loadLudwig = "lw.html";


$("#work a:first-child").click(function() {
  $("#work").fadeTo('slow', 0, function() {
    $("#work").load(loadLudwig, function(){
      $("#work").fadeTo('slow', 1);
    });
  });
}); 
// (& this part is working fine)
```

The relevant HTML (on the original page) is like this (its a grid of images embedded within anchor tags):

```
<section id="work">
  <a href="#">...img and svg stuff</a>
</section>
```

I tried many variations of:

```
$("#close-button").click(function() {
  $("#work").fadeTo('slow', 0, function () {
    $("#work").load('home.html #work', function() {
      $("#work").fadeTo('slow', 1);
    });
  });
});
```

but this loads the content very strangely / some of the original functionality of `#work` is lost.

How do I get my close button to navigate back to the original state of `#work`?

Comment: What do you mean with loss of functionality? Also, a recommendation, store ```$("#work")``` in a variable, to avoid unnecessary lookups

Comment: In #work, i have svgs which animate over imgs when the user hovers over the anchors. This goes away. Also, a class I have on the section tag (with id="work") gives #work a margin to accommodate a fixed navigation bar. Using jQuery in this way to load back the content doubles the effect of that margin class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the jquery documentation for `.load()` is stated that:

> #### Script Execution
>
> When calling .load() using a URL without a suffixed selector
>   expression, the content is passed to .html() prior to scripts being
>   removed. This executes the script blocks before they are discarded. If
>   .load() is called with a selector expression appended to the URL,
>   however, the scripts are stripped out prior to the DOM being updated,
>   and thus are not executed. An example of both cases can be seen below:
>
> Here, any JavaScript loaded into #a as a part of the document will
>   successfully execute.
>
> ```
> 1. $( "#a" ).load( "article.html" );
> ```
>
> However, in the following case, script blocks in the document being
>   loaded into #b are stripped out and not executed:
>
> ```
> 1. $( "#b" ).load( "article.html #target" );
> ```

This is a probable cause for lack of functionality.

I'd also look into event binding. In your code examples you're using `.click` but if you are loading content or you are creating elements on-the-fly you should be favoring [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/). This method delegates events instead of just binding them to a DOM node.

I'd recommend you reading the whole article.

### EDIT:

Here is a quick n'dirty way of achieving the effect

```
// pages to load
var loadLudwig = "lw.html",
    $ludwig,

    $work = $('#work'),
    $workContent = $work.children(),

    $closeButton = $("#close-button");

$work.find('a:first-child').click(function() {
  $work.fadeTo('slow', 0, function() {
    //Here is the tricky part
    //Detaching keeps all the jQuery data on the elements
    $workContent.detach();

    //The first time, load the content, 
    //if the content is already loaded
    //append it to the container
    if(!$ludwig){
        $work.load(loadLudwig, function(){
          //Save the content in a var
          //so you can reuse it later
          $ludwig = $work.children();
          $work.fadeTo('slow', 1);
        });
    } else {
        $ludwig.appendTo($work);
        $work.fadeTo('slow', 1);
    }
  });
});

$closeButton.click(function() {
  $work.fadeTo('slow', 0, function () {
    //Remove the old content, don't worry
    //because is stored in $ludwig
    $work.children().detach();

    //Instead of reloading the content, just
    //attach the fragment again
    $workContent.appentTo($work);        
    $work.fadeTo('slow', 1);
  });
});
```

Comment: thank you so much for the time you spent on this, man. I honestly appreciate it. I commented out my old code and used yours; Everything is working except the close button. When i hit #close-button, all of #work disappears.

Comment: actually there was a typo (the last .appendTo), however now the new content fades out, but just reloads itself (not reloading the old content)

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to save the html somewhere. For example:

```
// Top of file
var oldHTML = "";

// Lots of stuff...

$("#work a:first-child").click(function() {
  $("#work").fadeTo('slow', 0, function() {
    // Store the old html
    oldHTML = $("#work").html();
    $("#work").load(loadLudwig, function(){
      $("#work").fadeTo('slow', 1);
    });
  });
});

// Code for the close button

$("#close-button").click(function() {
  $("#work").fadeTo('slow', 0, function () {
    $("#work").html(oldHTML).fadeIn("slow");
  });
});
```

Alternatively, instead of replacing the html, you could create another child. Of course, you might have to slightly change your markup.

```
<section id="work">
  <div id="oldHTML">
    <a href="#">...img and svg stuff</a>
  </div>
  <div id="newSection" style="display:none;">
  </div>
</section>
```

Then replace `$("#work")` with `$("#oldHTML")` in your first piece of code like so:

```
$("#oldHTML a:first-child").click(function() {
  $("#oldHTML").fadeTo('slow', 0, function() {
    $("#oldHTML").hide();
    $("#newSection").load(loadLudwig, function(){
      $("#newSection").show().fadeTo('slow', 1);
    });
  });
});

// Code for the close button

$("#close-button").click(function() {
  $("#newSection").fadeTo('slow', 0, function () {
    $("#newSection").hide();
    $("#work").fadeIn("slow");
  });
});
```